# zend framework 2 - replace default phprenderer strategy

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm starting to get into Zend Framework 2, and one of the things that I'd like to do is create an intercept that strips all the tabs out of template files before the view vars are inserted into them.

I gather that I'd have to implement my own render strategy, but I can't quite figure out how to replace the default one (phprenderer). Is it just a matter of setting a strategy of the same name with a higher value then the default one?

Comment: You may find samsonasiks blog interesting: http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-create-custom-view-strategy/

Comment: Thank you, reading his blog started me on the right direction, and looking at Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php, it looks like what I want isn't possible, as the template is executed (render()), in which case the variables within the template would be rendered at the same time as the template itself.

Comment: actually, I've found a filter located here http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Filter_Minify_Html+-+Nick+Daugherty that looks like exactly what I was looking for, however, I'm having trouble getting zf2 to use my custom filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I've solved the issue by adding a Filter

```
namespace Application\Filter;

use Zend\Filter\FilterInterface;

class FilterMinifyHTML implements FilterInterface {

    public function filter($value) {

        return \Minify_HTML::minify($value, array(
            'cssMinifier' => array('Minify_CSS', 'minify'),
            'jsMinifier'  => array('JSMin', 'minify'),
        ));

    }

}
```

And then applied the filter as such (within `PhpRenderStrategy.php`)

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param  PhpRenderer $renderer
 */
public function __construct(PhpRenderer $renderer) {
    $this->renderer = $renderer;
    $filterChain = new FilterChain();
    $filterChain->attach(new FilterMinifyHTML());
    $this->renderer->setFilterChain($filterChain);
}
```